# How to omit resources directory when using lein uberjar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am building a MIDI application with Clojure and Leiningen, and I am including some example MIDI files in the `resources` directory for testing on the REPL. However, I would like to exclude these resources when using `lein uberjar`. I am not sure if this is possible, or if the best place for test files such as these is in the `resources` directory. I couldn't find anything specific to this... is there a way to exclude with `uberjar-exclusions` in `project.clj`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach to your problem would be to have a separate resource directory for development purposes, and have it configured separately in your `dev` profile in `leiningen`.

```
 :profiles {:dev {:resource-paths ["dummy-data"] ...
```

Remember settings get merged into existing ones, so you don't need to specify the standard `resources` path.

Look at the [sample project here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj), and [profiles doc here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md).